# Redis StringSetAsync returns false in Unit Tests using Moq

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, redis, moq

I am currently writing unit tests for a RedisProvider Class for my Solution. I have a method in my class that sets a key in the Redis Cache:

```
public async Task<bool> StringSetAsync(string key, string value)
{
   var cache = multiplexer.GetDatabase();
   //Some other stuff
   result = await cache.StringSetAsync(key, value);
   return result;
}
```

In my unit tests I have the following setup:

```
   var mockMultiplexer = new Mock<IConnectionMultiplexer>();

   mockMultiplexer.Setup(_ => _.IsConnected).Returns(true);
   mockMultiplexer.Setup(_ => _.Configuration).Returns(MockedData.CacheConnectionString);

   var mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();

   mockMultiplexer
         .Setup(_ => _.GetDatabase(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
         .Returns(() => mockDatabase.Object);

   RedisCacheProvider mockedCacheProvider = new RedisCacheProvider(new Mock<ILogger<RedisCacheProvider>> 
 ().Object, mockMultiplexer.Object);

   var result = await mockedCacheProvider.StringSetAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>());
```

When I run the above code for my unit test, the result that I receive is always false. Is there a way to get a true result? What is wrong over here?

Answer (score 2):

I realized that this should be mocked by the services using the class rather than validating this on the class itself.

Here you go:

```
            mockedCacheProvider.Setup(h => h.StringSetAsync(
                 It.IsAny<string>(),
                 It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(() => true);
```